# CentOS network connection breaks every 5 min

Tags: linux, networking, centos, networkmanager

I installed CentOS 6.2 about a month ago and it worked fine. Two days ago I saw that the internet connection is broken, so I reconfigured it. I was able to use it but after a few minutes it broke again. I realize the network configuration is reset every 5 minutes. How can I repair it?

I use Static IP.

Comment: There is a big regression in the RHEL kernel for some intel cards. To the date, there are only several temporary workarounds available. Do you have intel card? What kernel says?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some more information? How are you configuring your network connection, static IP or DHCP? Are you manually editing the configuration files? Is this a wireless or wired network connection?

Comment: Landline ? or wireless, please let us know

Answer (score -1):

My co-worker installed ubuntu and had his network connection break similar to the way you described it. He traced the problem to using wireless n (his network connection was over a wireless USB card that used an Atheros chipset). Once he turned the wireless router to mixed (instead of using wireless n exclusively) this problem went away.

YMMV.